# SGE - limit a user to a certain host, using resource quota configuration

Tags: gridengine

Is it possible to limit a user to a particular host, using the Resource Quota Configuration option in qmon for Sun Grid Engine?

I'm thinking of a line to the effect of:

```
{
...
limit users {john} to hostname=compute-1-1.local
}
```

[The documentation](http://wikis.sun.com/display/gridengine62u5/Managing+Resource+Quotas) mentions built in resource types: **slots, arch, mem_total, num_proc, swap_total**, and the ability to make custom types.

Details: SGE 6.1u5 on Rocks

update:

The above rule seems to be valid, since

- using an unknown hostname
- mangling the resource name 'hostname'

both cause errors

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{
  name=Limit_john
  limit users {john} hosts !compute-1-1.local to slots=0
}
```

(Note, I didn't test this, but it should work)